# Android dalvikvm can't find/link to class

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been working on an app for some time now and recently it keeps crashing on startup.

The error that causes it to crash is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` on my `launcher` `activity`. I've launched and debugged my app tons of times with no problems so I think I must've accidently changed something in a configuration file somewhere but I can't work out where.

I've checked the `manifest` file and there's nothing wrong, the path for the `activity` is correct and I've looked through the `class` file itself and again the `package` prefix is correct. I've also gone through the file directory and there's nothing wrong there either.

I tried changing the launcher `activity` to another one inside the same application and it runs with no problem, I've also tried creating a new launcher `activity` and that runs with no problem.

However, when I create a new `activity` and paste in all the code from the one that crashes the whole app crashes again. Even when the new `activity` has a different class name.

Also just before the app crashes I get two warnings:

`Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/bend/...` and `Link of class 'Lcom/bend/... failed`

Now everything in my app is `com.bend...` **NOT** `Lcom.bend...` but I can't find anywhere where it's written `Lcom.` But I don't know if that's the cause of the problem or just a change the system does.

I know it's a real obscure problem but I just cannot figure it out. Any help would be awesome.

EDIT: I've just tried running another app I've done that's has a similar design and it's doing exactly the same thing.

I've just recently updated the SDK. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it by creating an entirely new Android project and copying the java files and resources etc. into the new project.

I think it might have been the  `v4 support library` that was causing the problem. I'm using a lot of `Fragments` so was relying heavily on it. Though I tried replacing the .jar file from an app that worked and it didn't seem to help...

In any case it was nothing to do with any of the classes or the `manifest` file.